# python - How would I run code like a normal script (in addon)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up an array of certain PoseBones by scanning all the bones in the blender. But attempt to loop through all the objects via

```py
for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    print(ob.name)
```

I get this error

```py
AttributeError: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Here's the source code: https://github.com/kojocrash/Blender-Weld-Plugin/tree/master/weld

I put the piece of code at the end of weld_op.py

Comment: Don't access data before the add-on is properly registered. Instead create an operator which performs these actions in its  `execute` function.

Comment: Will the execute function run immediately after registration?

Comment: There are two options, usually add-ons should perform such action after user input, e.g. by pressing a button or after a certain event occured because the add-on has registered an [application handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#module-bpy.app.handlers).

Comment: I think the application handler is what I was looking for. I'll try it when I get home. All these things are new to me because I started python yesterday lol